# Can vsftpd handle DOS\Windows style backslash in path names?

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

Is there an option to allow backslash in path on vsftpd?

Example problem from script in use.

```
CD FTPUSER\FROM_FOLDER  
CD: Failed changing remote folder FTPUSER\FROM_FOLDER! (Remote sever replay: 550 Failed to change directory.)
```

Similar to pure-ftpd

/etc/pure-ftpd/pure-ftpd.conf parameter:

```
allow_backslash_in_path
```

!Note there is not an option to change the scripts as they are on client side:

Comment: There isn't one in [Manpage of VSFTPD.CONF](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html)

Comment: No I already checked there, badly phrased question.  
I was more looking for some hack or hidden option.